# Can't Change CSS Bottom with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble getting the "else" bit of this working. Anyone know what the problem is?

```
var navOpen = false;
                if (navOpen == false) {
                    $("nav").click(function() {
                        $(this).css("bottom","0");
                        navOpen = true;
                    });
                } else {
                    $("nav").click(function() {
                        $(this).css("bottom","-84");
                        navOpen = false;
                    });
                }
```

Comment: Where is the rest of the code? yo are setting `navOpen` to false just before the `if`, so it will never evaluate the else bit.

Comment: You need to specify 'px' or '%' to the -84.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The condition is in the wrong place.

```
 var navOpen = false;
 $("nav").click(function() {
      if (navOpen == false) {
           $(this).css("bottom","0");
           navOpen = true;
      } else {
           $(this).css("bottom","-84px");
           navOpen = false;
      }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. Shouldn't code late at night, things go over my head lol. I'll accept when it'll let me in a few minutes.

Answer (score 5):

You are binding several handlers to the same element, you can use `css` method:

```
$("nav").click(function() {
   $(this).css("bottom", function(i, bottom) {
      return bottom === '0px' ? '-84px' : '0px';
     // return navOpen ? '-84px' : '0px';
   });
})
```

Comment: Beat me to it. You were missing the unit (px) and binding multiple time (super bad).

Comment: He might need to do more with the `navOpen` variable, but this is an elegant solution +1

Answer (score 4):

Try with

```
$(this).css("bottom","-84px");
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to define metering (e.g px, %). CSS doesn't support just numering parameters like HTML attribute does.

Comment: Wow, can't believe I didn't try that. Thanks. I'm accpeting another answer because it fixed another issue I was having, but you get an upvote.